# Is it possible to enforce initial configuration of a page app?

Tags: facebook, configuration

I'm attempting to develop my first Facebook app that is designed to allow clients of our website to sell tickets to their events from their Facebook page as well as from our website. So when the administrator of a Facebook page adds our app as a page tab, I need to be able to find out who they are so I can load the relevant event data. There also needs to be additional include/exclude configurations and various other options, which will affect the behaviour of the app.

So my question is how is this situation best handled? When playing around with a basic sandboxed app, I seem to be able to just add the app directly to a page; there is no prompt for configuration, and I can't see any way of defining custom properties.

Is the 'edit_url' property the only way to achieve this? If so, is there a way of automatically directing the page admin to this link upon initial use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoding the [signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) recieved in your page will give you more insight.
From this you can retrieve page admins' UID's.
You'll need to manage the rest on your side...
In order to get the user id the user will have to grant your application basic [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. So can I assume that when the client accesses the app from their own page, the value of $signed_request['page']['admin'] will be true, but for everyone else (customers who can buy tickets) it will be false?

Comment: indeed..
$signedRequest['page'] - 
`A JSON object containing the page id string, the liked boolean if the user has liked the page, the admin boolean if the user is an admin. Only available if your app is an iframe loaded in a Page tab.`

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently doing a somewhat similar app and, just like Lix said, I used the signed_request variable to detect the page where the tab is installed. Then, based on the page's ID, I retrieve the proper content.

To also give your users an admin page, add a Page Tab Edit URL in your app configuration where you can redirect your users to a custom panel where they can edit their app.

Comment: It sounds like that's the best way to approach it then, thanks for the clarification.